# Custom Taxonomy Archive Page to display either ALL listings or only from URL

Tags: wp-query, urls

I'm using Toolset.com for Custom Post Types and Taxonomy and OxygenBuilder for page building in Wordpress. I've created a custom post type called Social Ritual (social-ritual) with a custom taxonomy called Playing Field (playing-field).

I'm trying to develop the Social Ritual Archive Page.
Initially I want this page to display all Social Rituals, like the Blog page displays all Posts. But if a user clicks on the taxonomy for a Social Ritual I would like it to load the Social Ritual Archive Page but only load the Social Rituals that fit that taxonomy.

As of now, if a user clicks on a Playing Field (life-games) for instance, it takes them to my-site.com/playing-field/life-games and the Social Ritual Archive Page loads, but my WP Query isn't done right.

I'm at the point where I am realizing I'm not even sure how to build the necessary WP Queru to do this.

How do I tell WP Query that I want to display ALL social-ritual unless the URL says my-site.com/playing-field/ ?

Comment: `/playing-field/life-games` is supposed to be a term archive which means it would only display posts in the `life-games` term/category, so I'm guessing you're not using the correct templates, e.g. `taxonomy.php` for all taxonomies. And, "my WP Query isn't done right" - you shouldn't be making new `WP_Query` instance on an archive page if the purpose is to change the main query/loop - use the `pre_get_posts` hook instead for that purpose.

Comment: Technically, I'm not creating an actual taxonomy.php page. I am using OxygenBuilder. I create a template file and assign it to the taxonomies and post types necessary (social-ritual & playing_field in this instance). Then I have to create a string query for their tool that passes to the WP Query to generate the output. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know OxygenBuilder, but if you can show your code (your template code and the string query), maybe I can give you some suggestions. Or you could try asking in OxygenBuilder forums.